# How can I find out why my PC won't start?

Tags: hardware-failure

I have a PC that I build myself, it was working for two years now it doesn't show anything.
These are the parts:
- AMD FX Series FX-6350 6x 3.90GHz So.AM3+BOX

- 8GB Crucial Ballistix Sport DDR3-1600 DIMM CL9 Dual Kit
- MSI 970A-G43 AMD 970 So.AM3+ Dual Channel DDR3 ATX Retail
- BitFenix Shinobi USB 3.0 Midi Tower
- 500 Watt be quiet! Pure Power L8 Non-Modular 80+ Bronze
- 8GB MSI Radeon RX 580 Gaming X 8G Aktiv PCIe 3.0 x16 (Retail)

The problem:
A few days ago on startup it only showed a black screen, not even BIOS was possible. A day later it started completly but the next restart again this problem.

CPU Fan is running, Case Fans are running, Graphic Card lights are on. But the fans of the graphic card didn't even do a start up spin. The one time it turned on the graphic card fans were running fast.

What I tried so far:

Completly removed the graphic card and put it in a different PCI-E slot that didn't help.
Used different monitors.

What I am going to try:

Hard reset of BIOS

Getting a motherboard speaker

Removing one RAM

Maybe getting a new CMOS battery?

Trying to find a working graphic card to check with that?

Getting a new CMOS battery

My thoughts what the problem could be:

- bad graphic card
- bad mainboard
- CMOS battery empty but that should simply give an error right?

What could be the root of my problem and how can I find that out?

Comment: If no useful message (e.g. beeps, led flashes) from your pc then your only way to make sure what's the problem is to put the components of your pc into another one and see which one makes the other computer to fail start.

Comment: Sorry got to get used to the formatting here. Should be more readable now. Getting a mainboard speaker is on my todo list the mainboard doesn't seem to have one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.

Get a motherboard speaker from an old computer. Plug it into the motherboard, remove all RAM sticks, and power on the computer.

The motherboard should give a beep code signifying that there is no RAM installed. If it doesn't, the motherboard has gone bad.